# limit pagination to 4 pages php

Tags: php, pagination

This is the code I use to create pagination page. I want to limit pagination to max 4 pages. I'm trying to limit the page number shown,and look for many examples .. Can get a little hints? Thank you.

```
($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
```

Comment: Loop from 1 to 4 instead of from 1 to 1?

Comment: (P.S. - There's no "pagination" happening here.  You're just asking how a loop works.  And how to count to 4.)

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in loop give it limit 1 to 4

```
($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
```